# How do Badass Tokens work?

Tags: borderlands-2

After completing some challenges, I've noticed I have some unspent Badass tokens on the Badass Rank tab. The description text says:

> Complete challenges to earn Customization items and Badass Ranks. Badass ranks earn you tokens which can be spent on permanent character upgrades that apply to ALL characters associated with your gamer profile.

How do these ranks and tokens work? I'm Badass Rank 9, which gave me three tokens. When I spend these tokens, are the effects I can unlock random, or is there a set progression somehow? What are the Customization items?

In general, how do Badass Ranks, tokens, and Customization items work?

Comment: The article at http://venturebeat.com/2012/09/17/breaking-borderlands-2-easy-money-xp-eridium-boss-fights-and-tokens/ has a couple ideas on how to earn some tokens quick.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your Badass Rank is a universal stat that applies to all of your characters, and all of your characters contribute to your rank.

You get Badass Ranks from completing the challenges outlined in the Badass menu (default <kbd>J</kbd> on pc). You can see these challenges in a list on the right-hand side. Some challenges are tiered, and reward you with more and more Badass Ranks and customization items as you advance up in tiers. Some challenges are one-off and provide a one-time reward. You can complete a challenge once with each character, which effectively allows you to endlessly increase your Badass rank as you create more characters. You can also track challenges by clicking on them in the list.

You get more Badass Tokens as you accumulate Badass Ranks. The current rate is unknown, but is estimated to be:

> Badass Rank = (Badass Tokens)<sup>9 / 5</sup>

Rounded down to the nearest whole number ([source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Badass_Rank#Badass_Tokens)).

Badass Tokens can be spent on a set of 5 random upgrades. Each upgrade can be purchased multiple times *to no maximum*, but there are diminishing returns. For any one upgrade that you invest in, the total accumulated magnitude of that upgrade is given by:

> Magnitude = (Badass Tokens spent on option)<sup>3 / 4</sup>

This means that if you invest 20 Badass Tokens to +% Gun Damage, you will have ~9.5% bonus gun damage on all of your characters ([source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Badass_Rank#Magnitude)).

Customization items are unlockables you can use to customize your character head and body skins/colors.

---

**On request**: here are the steps to calculate how many Badass Ranks you need for your next Badass Token:

1. Calculate your current expected Badass Tokens from your Badass Rank.
2. Calculate the expected Badass Rank for an additional token.
3. Determine the difference between the expected rank and your current rank.

> Expected Badass Tokens = (Current Badass Rank)<sup>5 / 9</sup>
>
> Expected Badass Rank = floor(ceil(Expected Badass Tokens)<sup>9 / 5</sup>)
>
> Ranks Needed = Expected Badass Rank - Current Badass Rank

For example, if you are at Badass Rank 1000, you have an expected 46.41 Badass Tokens (meaning you have 46 available). For one more token (47), you would need about 1022 Badass Ranks, meaning you will need about 22 more Badass Ranks before you get another token.

Comment: We *really* could use the nice math equation stuff that [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) has...

Comment: SadlyNot: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5384/27963 made that a meta question for you.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot thanks for the web-fu edit :)

Comment: I went looking for the same answers as the guy who asked this question in the first place, but the is one thing I still want to figure out that you didn't explain. Out of the five random stats that are given from each badass point are they completely random or does what you do in the game give more of a chance for a certain stat to pop up? i.e using guns to cause damage makes the stat "Gun Damage", or causing a lot of critical hit make the "Gun Accuracy" more of a chance to pop up? I only want to clarify because I'm at rank 2054 and I've only seen "Gun Damage" (Which I always assigning when it

Comment: @Phantom0x0 That's an interesting question ... I was certain that it's random but it's worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed there's no real pattern but in fact if you invest in one stat it becomes more rare until you start equalling out the other stats.
Two ways I discovered this:

- after buying multiple upgrades for the recoil reduction and gun accuracy they stopped showing up all together until the rest of my stats started catching up.
- I log in and sometimes I will have nearly three hundred unspent tokens (may be a glitch not sure)

My rank is now 20,522. I am only level 41.

Redeeming all of the tokens by selecting the first stat of five resulted in all of my stats being the same within about 1.7% of each other.