# How do Badass Ranks convert to Badass Tokens?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Badass Tokens work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84761/how-do-badass-tokens-work)

When completing some challenges, I'll get 1, 5, 50, 100 "Badass Rank," which increments the large white number and occasionally grants Badass Tokens for stat upgrades.

It's unclear how many I need for my next token. How often are tokens awarded, and how can I determine the number of ranks necessary for the next one?

Comment: This doesn't fit within the scope of the linked question, but good eye

Comment: It absolutely does.  I even asked for clarification because the answer does not address it. Try offering a bounty on the linked question.

Comment: I can adjust the similar answer to answer this question earlier on, since it is of the most interest to players. However, I'm ok with answering here too.