# Bad math in Borderlands 2 Badass Tokens?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Badass Tokens work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84761/how-do-badass-tokens-work)

I've noticed that I am granted a +0.4% increase in stats with each Badass Token spent... Until I reach 8.4%. Then the game says: "+0.4%" but only gives me 0.3% for a total of +8.7%. After that point each token gives a +0.4% just like before. What is up with that?

Comment: Question closed, but not answered.

Comment: It's probably just a rounding error.  Take a closer look at the linked post and double check the math for yourself.