# How do Badass Rank modifiers in B2 affect stats?

Tags: borderlands-2

All we're given is the percentage increase (e.g Critical Hit Damage +7.2%). Is this damage
additive (Crit damage = Card Damage X (2.0 + .072)
or 
multiplicative (Crit damage = Card Damage X (2.0 X 1.072)?

I understand the actual equation for Damage calculation is more complex, with Skill Bonuses being factored in at the lowest level: if a more appropriate question is whether Badass bonuses are factored as skill bonuses (modifying damage as it's dealt) or inherent item bonuses (modifying the stats seen on item cards BEFORE other bonuses are factored), then please answer that. My primary concern is where Badass bonuses fit into any given equation and just how effective they actually are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Badass Tokens work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84761/how-do-badass-tokens-work)

Comment: That question and the answers refer to obtaining the tokens and how much each token is worth as time progresses. I'm asking where the bonuses obtained from spending the tokens actually factor into your stats. Thanks though.

Comment: I'll do some testing for you and answer in a bit after results

Answer (score 2):

After testing with different characters (Mechromancer, Zero, and Gunzerker) and weapons (SMG, Pistol, Sniper) and using unspec'd skilltrees, and upgraded ones... Badass tokens and their effects appear to be one of the last things calculated when deciding things like accuracy and damage.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, it's good to know that little percentage is tacked onto the end of things.

Comment: I don't want to come off as having selfish intentions, but if the answer helped consider up-voting it or accepting it as a correct answer, it is greatly appreciated and will help let other people know that this question was answered.